# How to make a mock object throw an exception in Google Mock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, exception, throw, googlemock

With Google Mock 1.7.0, I have a mock object with a method, and I want to expect it to be called, and in this case the mocked method should throw an exception.

```
ObjectMock object_mock_;
EXPECT_CALL(object_mock_, method())
  .Times(1)
  .WillRepeatedly(???);
```

Is there a Google Mock action that throws an exception?  I did not find it in the documentation, yet I doubt that nobody has needed it so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just write a simple action that throws an exception:

```
ACTION(MyThrowException)
{
    throw MyException();
}
```

And use it as you would do with any standard action:

```
ObjectMock object_mock_;
EXPECT_CALL(object_mock_, method())
  .Times(1)
  .WillRepeatedly(MyThrowException());
```

There's also a googlemock standard action [`Throw()`](http://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cheat_sheet.md#side-effects), that supports throwing exceptions as action taken (Note that `MyException` must be a copyable class, to get this working!):

```
ObjectMock object_mock_;
EXPECT_CALL(object_mock_, method())
  .Times(1)
  .WillRepeatedly(Throw(MyException()));
```

Find the full documentation for `ACTION` and parametrized `ACTION_P<n>` definitions in the [GoogleMock CookBook](http://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#writing-new-actions-quickly-quicknewactions).

Comment: error: macro "ACTION_P" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given

Comment: @user1735594 Sorry, indeed `ACTION_P` is intended to receive extra parameters, which aren't needed in your case. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I fairly don't get why this answer received a downvote? That can't have really something to do with it's content, but was probably meant personally.

Comment: Can you tell us what #include we need for Throw to work? It isn't found when I include `#include <gmock/gmock.h>` and 
`#include <gtest/gtest.h>`

Answer (score 27):

The syntax for this is `Throw(exception)`, where exception is any copyable value.

```
ObjectMock object_mock_;
EXPECT_CALL(object_mock_, method())
  .Times(1)
  .WillRepeatedly(Throw(exception));
```